# MailKit Identify that message is html or plain text

Tags: c#, email, mailkit, document-body, mimekit

I am newbie in C#. I have a very basic question regarding the sending mail using Mailkit library.
I have a method which send the email that is perfectly fine.Please have a look on my method below.

```
public void SendMessage(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
```

Now my problem is I need to identify that body which are coming is plain text,rich text or html text.

Previously I have done as a plain text so it was easy for me like below you can see

```
 var bodyMessage = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = body
            };
            message.Body = bodyMessage;
```

but how we identify that coming body message is plain,rich or html ?
or I need to create Text part in if and else condition.
A short example will be really helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Who calls that `SendMessage` method? It is not trivial to absolutely correctly detect html.

Comment: In most Mailclients I know, there is no auto-detection of body type that I am aware of. I'd have a Setting for the "default" for new messages and _maybe_ also an "override" to switch types for a single message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to this:

```
public enum TextFormat {
    PlainText,
    Html,
    RichText
}

public void SendMessage(string from, string to, string subject, string body, TextFormat format)
```

Now you can tell the method what kind of text it is so you don't have to guess.

Comment: @All : Thanks for your reply.
I have written my own method that will detect plain text or HTML.
So I marked this as resolve.